# RxJava Solution to prevent blocking in multithread environment

Tags: rx-java

The task:

I have a set of unique values - `["A","B","C","D"]`
Multiple threads are trying to remove values from it.
When it becomes empty the code should notify some listeners.

In Java I need to block threads each time I remove element and check if the collection is empty to prevent sending 2 same events at a time.

So can I implement it somehow with RxJava without blocking execution?

P.S. In real program there are many of that sets.

Comment: please post some code and the intend, otherwise we can not help you. RxJava is all about immutability and reacting to change on event bases. I don not see any of the requirements satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but sounds like you'd want something like this:

```
final class RxSet {
    final Set<String> elements = new HashSet<String>();

    final AsyncSubject<Object> onEmpty = AsyncSubject.create();

    public RxSet(String... initialValues) {
         elements.addAll(Arrays.asList(initialValues));
    }

    public Observable<Object> onEmpty() {
         return onEmpty;
    }

    public boolean take(String item) {
        boolean wasEmpty = false;
        boolean isEmpty = false;
        boolean success = false;

        synchronized (this) {
            wasEmpty = set.isEmpty();
            success = set.remove(item);
            isEmpty = set.isEmpty();
        }

        if (!wasEmpty && isEmpty) {
            onEmpty.onNext("became empty");
            onEmpty.onComplete();
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```